# Как реализовать проверку совпадения символа из свойства объекта

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

На learnjavascript есть такое задание.

> Есть объект salaries с зарплатами. Напишите код, который выведет сумму
>   всех зарплат.

```
"use strict";

var salaries = {
  "Вася": 100,
  "Петя": 300,
  "Даша": 250
};

//... ваш код выведет 650
```

Я это задание немного усложнил. Решил конвертировать зарплату, то есть, если зарплата в долларах, например "Вася": "100$"; то пересчитываем её в рубли (с помощью какого-то коэф.) и т.д.

Вот пример кода, там в комментариях, с чем надо помочь.
https://jsfiddle.net/psinegmatic/eb86f4mo/2/

```js
function isEmpty(obj) {

  var sum = 0;
  for (var name in obj) {

    var sallaryRaw = obj[name];
    var sallaryValue = parseInt(sallaryRaw, 10);
    var sallaryRub = sallaryValue * coff;
    var coff = 1;

    if (sallaryRaw.search(/$/i) != -1) { //Вот это нужно исправить 
      coff = 55;
    } else {
      coff = 1;
    }
    sum += sallaryRub;
  }

  return sum;

}

var salaries = {
  "Вася": "100$",
  "Петя": 300,
  "Даша": 250
};

alert(isEmpty(salaries));
```

Comment: Первое что бросается в глаза - ваши расчёты идут ДО того как происходит вычисление коэффициента, вы намеренно всё переставили?

Comment: Вот о каком порядке я говорю: https://jsfiddle.net/eb86f4mo/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function isEmpty(obj) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var name in obj) {
    var sallaryRaw = obj[name];
    var sallaryValue = parseInt(sallaryRaw, 10); // 10 - значение по умолчанию, его указывать не обязательно
    // Первая ошибка. Сейчас coff === undefined, следовательно sallaryRub = NaN
    var sallaryRub = sallaryValue * coff; 
    var coff = 1;
    /* В этой строчке две ошибки:
    if (sallaryRaw.search(/$/i) != -1) {  
1. $ в регулярных выражениях - спецсимвол конца строки. 
чтобы найти $ как символ, надо его экранировать: */
    var regex = /\$/i;
    /* 2. Метод search есть только у строк. 
Числа сначала надо привести к строке: */
    try{ 
        sallaryRaw.search(regex) 
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
        console.log(typeof sallaryRaw);
        sallaryRaw = sallaryRaw.toString();
    }
    if (sallaryRaw.search(regex) != -1) {
      coff = 55;
    } else {
      coff = 1;
    }
    // Вот теперь можно считать
    var sallaryRub = sallaryValue * coff;
    sum += sallaryRub;
  }
  return sum;
}

var salaries = {
  "Вася": "100$",
  "Петя": 300,
  "Даша": 250
};
alert(isEmpty(salaries));

// PS как бы это сделал я
const exchange_rate = 55;
const regex = /\$/i;
const toRub = salary => {
    if(regex.test(salary)) salary = exchange_rate * parseInt(salary);
    return salary;
}
const sum = Object.values(salaries).reduce((sum, salary) => sum + toRub(salary), 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: зачем делать `try`...`catch` если потом всегда делать `toString`? _console.log_ - непонятно где повис внутри `if`

Comment: @Grundy Чтоб продемонстрировать ошибку. лишний console.log ща поправлю